# Select last row mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$select1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT robotid FROM robotidsz ORDER BY robotid DESC LIMIT 1");
for ($i = $select1; $i <= 9999999; $i++) {
```

Above is my code, this should search from the last "RobotID known in the table to 9999999.

If i change $select1 to 1000000 this functions from 1000000-9999999 correctly however using this code nothing happens?

Comment: Because `mysqli_query` returns a resource, not an integer. You need to first fetch the object (or array) from the query.

Comment: $lastidd = mysqli_fetch_object($select1); Like this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to extract the result from your query. At the moment, you're assigning `$i` an initial value of the `Resource` returned.

The following demonstrates how to solve this:

```
$select1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT robotid FROM robotidsz ORDER BY robotid DESC LIMIT 1");
$result = mysqli_fetch_object($select1);

for ($i = $result->robotid; $i <= 9999999; $i++) 
{
    // Do your stuff...
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Works Perfect.